# How to append some string while in response of json in spring restful services

Tags: spring, jackson

this is the code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/find/city={city}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String getCity(@PathVariable String city) throws JsonParseException, IOException 
{
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    SimpleBeanPropertyFilter theFilter = SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept("id","miscellaneous","country","foundin","code","latlong","state");
    FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("myFilter", theFilter);

    return mapper.writer(filters).writeValueAsString(City_Repository.findByCityLikeIgnoreCase(city));
     }
```

in response:

```
[
  {
    "indexid": 65,
    "city": "Barcelona"
  },
  {
    "indexid": 158,
    "city": "Dillons Bay"
  },
  {
    "indexid": 232,
    "city": "East London"
  }]
```

I Required in response:

```
[ 
    {
        type: "airport", 
        "airport": { "indexid": 65, "city": "Barcelona" }, 
                   { "indexid": 158, "city": "Dillons Bay" }, 
                   { "indexid": 232, "city": "East London" }
]
```

Comment: Your required JSON is not a valid json.

Comment: You'd be better off leaving JSON serialization to the Spring+Jackson integration via `@ResponseBody` and just return your domain object, e.g. `City` that has a `List<Airport>` instead of converting to String manually. Also, the "/find/city={city}" is rather unorthodox.

Comment: can anyone help me out??